# Adding and Updating with LINQ to Entities

Tags: rest, linq-to-entities, savechanges

We are using L2E and REST in our project, and while I have been able to retrieve data from the db without issue, I am still not able to update or add new records to the db.  I imagine that it's a syntax problem (we're still new to to linq), but I haven't been able to figure it out.  We initially load the data in the dataservicecontext, and when updates are made they are stored in the `CurrencyManager.Current` of the binding source.  However, when I call `SaveChanges` nothing gets modified in the db, and I don't know why.

For example,

Loading the data:

```
 var customerQuery = Program.Proxy.Customers.Where(p => p.ContactId == g);
```

Saving the data:

```
 Program.Proxy.SaveChanges();
```

I've confirmed that the updated copy of the entity in memory is being tracked, so I don't need to call `AddObject`, but I get an error ("*The closed type Lynxphere.WindowsClient.LynxphereDataServices.Customers does not have a corresponding Customers settable property.*") if I try to call `AddLink`.  And I'm not even sure if this step is necessary.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show more of your code, e.g., the actual modifications.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what to show you.  The data pulled from the db in the entity is displayed in a variety of textboxes etc for the user to update.  I have confirmed that the updated data resides in the CurrencyManager, but I don't see how this gets mapped back to the entity for the db update.

Comment: Once again: The actual modification of the data. If you select, modify, and SaveChanges within a single object context, the changes will go back to the DB.

Comment: I thought that by binding the controls directly to the datasource (a textbox might have a databinding 'text' field of: customersBindingSource - Contacts.LastName), that the changes would be tracked and then SaveChanges would be enough to commit these changes to the db.  I take it that this is wrong?

Comment: ObjectDataSource works if the original context is alive. It sounds to me like you're not using the same context to save as you used to select, but (once more) hard to say without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on my repository pattern with a Save() function, published in the project below.
There is a EntityProductRepository implemented.
That might help you to do the Updates and Inserts correctly.

[openticket.codeplex.com](http://openticket.codeplex.com)